# How to do nickname searches in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

Hi guys so I have a question about nick name searches.

I have a very large database and in my Accounts Entity I have a firstname column. When a user searches for an account by first name, it is possible that they may be using a nickname. For example searching for Bob, should also return Robert.

The way I would think to do this would be to create a table called nickname, with two columns, the nickname, and name. That way we map bob->robert.

Then when doing the query make the where clause look like this "WHERE firstname IN (SELECT name FROM nickname WHERE nickname = 'bob')"

The two problems I have is, the query above seems very inefficient, and would be very slow over large data sets (I could be wrong here so please tell me if so, when I say large data set I mean 14 million rows).

The Second problem I have is where to get the Nickname data from. This is the only thing I have found so far: https://code.google.com/p/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup/downloads/list

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Filtering a large table against a small table with high selectivity is not slow. At least it's comparable to filtering directly with `WHERE column=value`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use full text search instead:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

This would allow you to add custom dictionaries, among other colorful features:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html

Comment: This is the method I'd suggest-- It should be faster, although you might have to rebuild the indexes if the dictionary changes.

Comment: Ok I will look into this. I assume I create a synonym dictionary for the matching

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar problem.  We had a table with name variations that were linked to an individual. This was for a database of authors.

We then created a mapping table with soundex and double metaphone entries for these names (pre-generated) then did queries against that table to find individuals.

If you're not familiar with soundex or double metaphone, they are phonetic algorithms to match when using misspellings and similiar names.  Soundex was developed for the US Census.

In our case, we already had the variations of every name the person published as rather than a generic list of names.  However, the soundex algorithm can help with similar spellings.  You'll still need to get a nickname list from somewhere, but this should help with the performance.

The reason I suggested two algorithms is that we had a lot of collisions using just one, but with both of those together it was a rather good filter. Double Metaphone worked better for non Western European names.

I'd suggest adding a front end element to let your customer service people (or customers) add their nickname too.  Customers can help you build up a nickname list and you can use known nicknames to help with fuzzy searches on others eventually.